# C# mysql insert command and converting ISO 8601 Time string

Tags: c#, mysql

What i have is a string that is ISO 8601 and I'm trying to insert it into a MySql table.  The table takes the date fine but does not recognize the time.

string myTime = "3/8/2011 5:36:54 PM" (this comes in ISO 8601 format).
string mytimeFormat = myTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM:SS");

and a basic insert into mysql statement.  The MySql table shows the date correctly, just not the time.  Any tips?

When i convert it using the string mytimeFormat it looks like '2011-03-08 17:36:54'  This is where MySql accepts the date just not the time.

Comment: "3/8/2011 5:36:54 PM"  is not in ISO 8601

Comment: The wiki for that format has something completely different. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations

Comment: Is the field type `DATETIME`? or just `DATE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to convert the string to a DateTime first, so the formatting can done properly.

```
string myTime = "3/8/2011 5:36:54 PM"; //(this comes in ISO 8601 format).
DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.Parse(myTime);
string mytimeFormat = myDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM:SS");
```

**Update**: In the format, a uppercase `M` is the month placeholder, use a lowercase `m` to get the minute:

```
myDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:SS")
```

Comment: Combining date and time representations to represent a single point in time (time point) is quite simple. It is in the format of <date>T<time> where the time designator [T] is used to show the start of the time component of the representation. Both the date and time components of the time point are any proper representations of date and time specified by the standard. For example, "2007-04-05T14:30" uses the extended formats for date and time [YYYY]-[MM]-[DD]T[hh]:[mm], while "20090621T0545Z" uses the basic formats [YYYY][MM][DD]T[hh][mm]Z

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you watch the case of your formatting string.
If using ToString from a DateTime object make sure you use:

```
myDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
```

You might also want to make sure any parsing you are doing is actually working before checking the output from the ToString.